# Google Sheet API is Not Working in Release Build

Tags: android, android-studio, google-sheets-api

Am using Google Sheet API in my Android App. It's working fine as expected in debug mode. Stopped working when I published it in the play store. Now App is getting crashed due to it. Users seem unhappy now!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you update the SHA-1 with the release SHA-1 in the Key restriction section at the Google developer console.

Steps:

1. Open the [Google Console](https://console.cloud.google.com/).
2. Select your project.
3. Select credentials.
4. Select your key.

You see the picture below explaining where to edit the SHA-1.

[image: SHA-1 field]

You can get the "Release certificate fingerprint" from the following command.

```
keytool -list -v -keystore your_keystore_name -alias your_alias_name
```